# Opening a fragment in another fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a view pager that has 3 fragments inside.
However, the first fragment has a listview.
I want to open a new fragment when I click on a ListView item.
I was able to make it work succefully with this code:

```
Fragment FullBrand = new FullBrand();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.framebrands, FullBrand);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
FullBrand.setArguments(bundle);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

However, when the new fragment launches, the viewpager is still there!
What to do? how can I get rid off them??
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to replace one fragment inside the view pager.

If you want to replace the view pager fragment (with it's 3 child) and to show other fragment you need to call the transaction in the FragmentActivity and replace it in the current container.

Add callback to the activity and replace the whole container in the activity when listview item clicked.

**Example to add listener**

in view pager fragment, declare your interface:

```
public interface OnViewPagerClickListener {
    public void onBlaBla(Object arg);
}
```

in your Fragment Activity:

```
public class MyFragmentActivity implement ViewPagerFragment.OnViewPagerClickListener
```

in your view pager fragment override onAttach & declare interface member

```
private OnViewPagerClickListener mCallback;

@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mCallback =(OnViewPagerClickListener) activity  **try catch this code**
    }
```

And wherever you want call the mCallback.onBlaBla(...)
and do the rest in the activity....
This is very summarize lesson for interfaces :)

More info about interface and callback [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) 
Good luck.

Comment: Yes exactly, that's what im trying to do. 

Can you offer more details about how to add a callback to the activity?

Comment: hey I did exactly what you told me to do and it worked. but I have a problem when the user clicks the back button, it exits the app instead of taking him to the previous fragment. any idea?

Comment: Simple search and you'll find the answer

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to remove the `ViewPager` instead better you can show the new Fragment (i.e FullBrand) in a `DialogFragment` . so If you click back it will bring you to old `ViewPager` only, it won't exit the app

To show a Dialog Fragment with **FullScreen** try the following code:

```
public class NewFragment extends DialogFragment {

private Dialog dialog;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_fragment_xml_here, container,
            false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(),
            android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    return dialog;
    }
}
```

Then call this NewFragment from your ListView item click to show this as NewScreen which will look like a new screen:

```
NewFragment fragment = new NewFragment();
fragment.show(fragmentManager, "NewFragment");
```

I hope it would help you.